# How to implement fetch inside a fetch in JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, url, fetch-api

I have to get the character names (not URLS) as the output at the `$(obj.characters)`, but I am unsure about how to implement it. I also need five names only using for loop. I have these two problems to clear.

API: https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books

```
document.body.innerHTML=`<div class="heading-container">
<h1>An Ice and Fire<h1>

</div>
<div id="mainContainer" class="main-container"></div>`;

const getData=async() => {
    try{
    const data=await fetch("https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books")
    const books= await data.json()
    mainContainer.innerHTML="";
    books.forEach(book => {
        displayData(book)
        
    });
}catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
}
};
getData();



const displayData=(obj)=> {
    mainContainer.innerHTML+=`
    <div class="container">
    <h1 class="css1">Name:<span>${obj.name}</span>, ISBN:<span> ${obj.isbn}</span></h1>
    <h2 class="css2"> Authors:<span>${obj.authors}</span></h2>
    <h3 class="cs3"> Number of Pages:<span>${obj.numberOfPages}</span><h3>
     
    <h4 class="css5">Publisher Name:<span>${obj.publisher}</span> , Release Date:<span>${obj.released}</span></h4>
    <h4 class="css6">Characters${obj.characters}</span></h4>
     </div>`

}
```

Comment: Looking at the [character list](https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters) it appears that **none of the characters** have a value for the `name` attribute. What then? It is unclear to me what you mean by "_I also need five names only using for loop_". Can you clarify both of these please?

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion, you have things too single-use. My implementation is creating a generic "getUrl" to get any resource from your chosen API, which can then be reused to iterate through characters when you need to.

Observe:

```
    const books = [];

    getUrl = async(url) => {
      try {
        const data = await fetch(url);
        return await data.json();
      } catch (error) { console.log('Failed to retrieve data: ', error); }
    }

    getBooks = () => {
      getUrl("https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books").then(data => {
        data.forEach(b => {
          const book = { Name: b.name, ISBN: b.isbn, Authors: b.authors, Pages: b.numberOfPages, Publisher: b.publisher, Released: b.released };
          let characters = [],
            charLen = b.characters.length >= 5 ? 5 : b.characters.length;
          for (let i = 0; i < charLen; i++) {
            getUrl(b.characters[i]).then(c => characters.push(c.name));
          }
          book.Characters = characters;
          books.push(book);
        });
      });
    }

    getBooks();
    console.log(books);
```

This will create a constant books object which will service your needs in your `displayData` function above (with capitalized property names). It is my opinion that you should also unpack the Authors and Characters lists using `<ul><li>` since the data may not be presented as aesthetically pleasing as you might expect with your current markup.

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {` probably want to add a check that `b.characters` has that many `i < 5 && i < b.characters.length;` Bug in your code is you are not awaiting the `getUrl` which you are not going to do in a forEach

Comment: @epascarello the API returns no less than 55 characters per book, so I felt it unnecessary to include. For the sake of good programming, though, I will add it in.